# Python send reply to a gmail message getting this error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, email, smtp

I have constructed the following code to reply to an existing email in my gmail account

```
replySubj = "Re: hello"
recipient = "test@acc.emailTest.com"
sender = "dummy1@gmail.com"
username = "dummy1@gmail.com"
password = "blahblahblah"

msg = MIMEMultipart('')
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = recipient
msg['Subject'] = replySubj
msg['In-Reply-To'] = uid
msg.attach(MIMEText("I received your message"))

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(sender, recipient, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

I keep getting this error --> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'
which relates to this line

```
server.sendmail(sender, recipient, msg.as_string())
```

when I remove .as_string()  I get this error:  TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Please note that uid is an integer

Comment: is `uid` an integer or a string?

Comment: uid is an integer

Comment: Thank you that was it.  I did --> msg['In-Reply-To'] = str(uid)  and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a hint from "entrez"  the solution is

msg['In-Reply-To'] = str(uid)

somehow i thought is I did: msg.as_string() it would make the whole thing string but since uid is an integer I have to convert it to string first